# Vue.elementDirective is not a function

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting the following error

```
Vue.elementDirective is not a function
```

This happened after trying to upgrade Vue. Sadly, I have no idea in which file this error is. I can't find elementDirective anywhere in the project. Does anyone know how this could potentially be fixed?

Thank you very much.

Regards,

Bart

Comment: `elementDirective` is only available on Vue 1.
If you're using Vue 2, you should use `.directive` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, however elementDirective doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the project. Do you know how this could be caused?

Comment: I should add that it does actually appear, but only in files in the /public folder, which we can't seem to make changes in

Comment: I don't have an idea on that. But maybe, it is somehow being generated by your third-party libraries?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually, thanks. Will look into it

Comment: no worries man. glad to help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rene Padillo mentioned, elementDirective is only available on Vue 1.

You need to use [Custom Directives](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#introduction) like so :

```
 const app = createApp({})

// make v-focus usable in all components
app.directive('focus', {
  /* ... */
})
```

Cheers